SQL disaggregate monthly data into daily rows
I'm using SQL in bigQuery
I need to disaggregate monthly data into daily entries and compute the total cost per day.
Input Data
StartDate    EndDate     IDCampaign  TotalCost
2024-01-01   2024-03-31  C1          50000
2024-02-01   2024-04-30  C2          12000

Output Data
StartDate    EndDate     IDCampaign  TotalCost
2024-01-01   2024-03-31  C1          555,55
2024-01-02   2024-03-31  C1          555,55
2024-01-03   2024-03-31  C1          555,55
2024-01-04   2024-03-31  C1          555,55
.
.
2024-03-31   2024-03-31  C1          555,55

I'm trying to do a CTE using GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY but I can not perform de calculation. Do you have any ideas? or maybe  to improve this query:
WITH DateRange AS (
  SELECT 
       StartDate, 
       EndDate
   FROM tmptable
)
SELECT 
  Day
FROM DateRange,
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(StartDate, EndDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS Day;

Thanks in advance.

Consider below approach (BigQuery)
select day as StartDate, EndDate, IDCampaign, cost as TotalCost
from your_table,
unnest(generate_date_array(StartDate, EndDate)) day,
unnest([TotalCost / date_diff(EndDate, StartDate, day)]) cost  

if applied to sample data in your question - output is


Thanks bro, this script help me a lot. I'll post another question since the business process has changed.

Consider something like:
with input_data as (
  select cast('2024-01-01' as date) as StartDate, cast('2024-03-31' as date) as EndDate, 'C1' as IDCampaign, 50000 as TotalCost
  union all
  select '2024-02-01', '2024-04-30', 'C2', 12000
),
date_spine as (
  select calendar_date from unnest(generate_date_array('2024-01-01', '2024-12-31', interval 1 day)) calendar_date
),
joined as (
  select
    date_spine.calendar_date as StartDate,
    input_data.EndDate as EndDate,
    input_data.IDCampaign,
    input_data.TotalCost / (date_diff(input_data.EndDate, input_data.StartDate, day)) as TotalCost
  from date_spine
  inner join input_data
    on date_spine.calendar_date between input_data.StartDate and input_data.EndDate
)
select * from joined
order by IDCampaign, StartDate

